# turkish character decode of nclob data to html in oracle

Tags: oracle, decode, nclob

I see nclob data in editor of oracle pl sql developer as

```
Detayları resmi yazı ile iletilen t&uuml;berk&uuml;loz ...
```

But I want to decode this into

```
Detayları resmi yazı ile iletilen tüberküloz ...
```

My sql query is like:

```
SELECT T.Aciklama "AÇIKLAMA",
...
```

How should I change my query to result as true decode.

Comment: Seeing HTML entities in a Oracle database makes me think that data comes from an HTML form and the HTML document's encoding doesn't support Turkish characters.

Comment: I tried to export it to excel with query and some c# code, result is same in excel.

Comment: You could simply `replace(source_string, '&uuml;', 'ü')` and repeat the same for all special html codes of your alphabet.

Comment: @serefbilge - Of course, exporting data does not alter data unless done wrong. I was just suggesting that perhaps you can store correct data in the first place. If that's not an option, I'm pretty sure C# can decode HTML entities.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - I use fck editor, and it makes it like that, it parses right when editing. Then, the problem occured when transport to excel needed. I should decode nclob to right format with query.

Comment: Er... CKEditor is an HTML editor so you'll also have HTML tags like `<p>` or `<span>`, won't you? Your data is HTML so you just handle it as such. Again, SQL is not a good tool to process HTML.

Comment: There is no problem with fck editor, the problem is with exporting to excel. To see it in excel in right format, I need to decode it into turkish chars.